# jQuery search filter on keyup advanced

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage with lots of li lists. i want to filter with multiple words.  as I type into the search field on keypress . using % for adding condition.

this is my

list

```
<input id="search" type="text" name="">

<ul class="list">
<li><p>catA - Alaska - item1 - subcat1</p></li>
<li><p>catB - Arizona - item2 - subcat3</p></li>
<li><p>catA - alaska - item1 - subcat1</p></li>
<li><p>catC - california- item3 - subcat1</p></li>
<li><p>catB - alaska - item1 - subcat1</p></li>
```

i am using this code for filtering items

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".class li").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
});
```

search query

```
cata%ala%cat1%
```

result expected

```
<li><p>catA - Alaska - item1 - subcat1</p></li>
```

how can i do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim();
  var v = value.split("%");
  $(".list li").each(function(j,k) {
    var s = true;
    $.each(v, function(i, x) {
      if (s) {
        s = $(k).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(x) > -1;
      }
    });
    $(this).toggle(s);
  });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase().trim();
  var v = value.split("%");
  $(".list li").each(function(j,k) {
    var s = true;
    $.each(v, function(i, x) {
      if (s) {
        s = $(k).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(x) > -1;
      }
    });
    $(this).toggle(s);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text" name="">

<ul class="list">
  <li>
    <p>catA - Alaska - item1 - subcat1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>catB - Arizona - item2 - subcat3</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>catA - alaska - item1 - subcat1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>catC - california- item3 - subcat1</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>catB - alaska - item1 - subcat1</p>
  </li>
```